# Do CSS Classes for custom list types affect page load speed?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I determine the impact of custom unordered lists on page load speed in Wordpress? I have about 15 of these in my custom CSS file, each adding a unique symbol (e.g. ) before each list item. Should I remove these custom lists to improve page load speed?

**Example:
**

```
.entry-content ul.mango-list {
    list-style: none;
}
.entry-content ul.mango-list li:before {
    content: '\';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    margin-left: -1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Load time is determined by how fast your connection is and how much data you're transmitting. If you pick a connection speed and [determine the size of the text](http://bytesizematters.com/) in question, you can calculate impact on load time.

Comment: >I haven't tried anything yet.

You should try some things! Also, you may find that you encounter a more rich answer from the [Webmasters stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  I have a strong feeling that an answer from that subdomain will be much more rich an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the dead code that your site does not use. I don´t know about WordPress, but in CSS generally you can use third party tools to remove dead CSS from your code. And removing lots of dead CSS will certainly increase the speed of your site.